# Kotlin: "val someVar = if (xx) 1 else 1.0", why is someVar an "Any"?

Tags: inheritance, types, casting, kotlin

First, I tried:

```
interface Super
class A : Super
class B : Super

val a = if (System.currentTimeMillis() >= 100) A() else B()
```

I pressed `Ctrl Q` to check the type of `a`. It's `Super`, as expected.

But when I tried:

```
val someVar = if (System.currentTimeMillis() > 0) 1 else 1.0
```

It says `someVar` is an `Any`. Shouldn't it be a `Number`?

Comment: Where do you check the type with `Ctrl Q`?

Comment: on the `someVar`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is, because your classes just inherit from one single interface. If you have a look at `Int` and `Double`

```
class Int : Number(), Comparable<Int>
class Double : Number(), Comparable<Double>
```

So it can not be determined which common type to use.

In such cases, you have to make the type explicit by

```
val someVar: Number = ...
```

Answer (score 5):

**The problem is**: Both `Double` and `Int` are sub types of `Number` **and** `Comparable`, i.e. they have two different super types.

If you change your example to the following, your variable will also be `Any` since then `A` and `B` are not only `Super` anymore:

```
interface Super
class A : Super, Serializable
class B : Super, Serializable

//a is of type Any
val a = if (System.currentTimeMillis() >= 100) A() else B()
```

You could explicitly declare the variable's type if you want it to be of type `Number`:

```
val someVar: Number = if (System.currentTimeMillis() > 0) 1 else 1.0
```